# Prevent Startpage from crashing

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller

I'm doing a site where I need to be able to show 3 users on the startpage from the database. The problem is that if I don't have 3 users in the Db, everything crashes and the rest of the startpage won't even show up.

I have google this and can't find any good solution. 
The solution I think about is to make another startpage without the method that makes the example users to show up, and only show the rest of the startpage.

But it most be any other better solution, I have a if statement that counts the users and do the method if it's more than three users.   `if (totalUsers >= 3)`

Is there anything I can put in the else so I skip the method that showing the example users, and just leave that part blank on the startpage?

Answer (score 1):

show us the code you are using.

it is not easy to help you if we don't know the code you are using.

So you have a list of users, then you can say 
`if(Users.Any()){
  // show users...
}`

Answer (score 1):

> The solution i think about is to make another startpage without the method that makes the example users to show up, and only show the rest of the startpage.

This is not a good solution. One better option is to use some Razor Code in your Index View ("startpage").

All you need is an empty div, which will show 3 users if there are enough or remain empty otherwise. Something like this:

```
<div>
    @{bool EnoughUsersToShow = /* your way for checking it here */}
    @{short count = 0}

    @if (EnoughUsersToShow)
    {
        <ul>
            @foreach (var user in Users)
            {
                @if (count <= 3)
                    <li>@user.Name</li>
                @count++
            }
        </ul>
    }
</div>
```

You have to provide more information in your question's description, especially code. People will provide you better answers and with way better code than this one.

Please give this a read: http://www.catb.org/esr/faqs/smart-questions.html

Hope this was helpful.

Comment: Maybe thats the way..   im using this right now to check if there is 3 or more.                                                                                       
var ctx = new DatingDbContext();
int totalUsers = ctx.Profiles.Count();
            if (totalUsers >= 3)

Comment: If your method is working, than thats it! Just assign the return value to the EnoughUsersToShow variable and it should work. You can find some good documentation and examples here -> https://www.learnrazorpages.com/

Answer (score 0):

You can handle the error by using try catch and finally statement in your code.

Please let me know if you get any problem.